# Can I extend 20 amp garage outlet? Or can I only move it?

Tags: receptacle, nec

In attached garage there is a receptacle with a single 20 amp outlet (marked as "Freezer" in a breaker panel). It is in inconvenient location. The idea is to extend this circuit to an area where I need outlets. After it this circuit will power 5-6 outlets.

I found this in NEC 2017 `[210.11 Branch Circuits Required (C) (4)]`:

```
(4) Garage Branch Circuits. In addition to the number of
branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at least
one 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be installed to
supply receptacle outlets in attached garages and in detached
garages with electric power. This circuit shall have no other
outlets.
```

Does it prevent me from extending this circuit? If yes - which options do I have? Either move or extend but add a new 20 amp circuit with a single outlet?

Comment: Are the new outlets going to be in the garage? Outside? Somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe the confusion is with definitions?  Art. 100 "Outlet  A point on the wiring system at which current is taken to supply utilization equipment", so hard wired light fixtures or fan junction boxes are outlets that are not allowed on the garage receptacle outlet circuits.

Comment: Yeah, that's the new EVSE rule.  They require a dedicated garage circuit "with no other outlets" so you can dedicate the full 20A (well, 16A) to a level 1 EVSE.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I think I got confused by the terms. Extending and installing more receptacle outlets are fine but powering lights/anything else hard wired is not. Got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as all the outlets are in the garage, you meet the language of the code.

The intent of the single outlet (marked freezer) would have been to minimize the possibility of the freezer being taken out by some other load tripping the circuit. You don't need to follow that intent, particularly if you are not also using it for a freezer.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease provided more details into the language of the code. Please refer to that comment for more details.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be reading something old. The 2002 through 2017 NECs that I have here do not say it in that way, they don't have the part about having no other outlets. That phrase IS there for Laundry areas, but not in the part about garages in general.

Comment: It's a part of 210.11 Branch Circuits Required (C) (4). I'm reading NEC 2017.